# Парсинг xml "изнутри" war

Tags: java, xml, dom, парсер, sax

Хочу положить в проект Java (jsp) внутрь файла war файл xml или json, в котором будут храниться данные подключения к mysql серверу.

Нигде не смог найти примера, как (например, через DOM или SAX) сделать парсинг xml именно изнутри проекта. С файлом, подключаемым "извне" находил, но как только не пытался прописать путь к файлу внутри проекта - Idea не видит этот файл.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно пример, как взаимодействовать с подобными файлами, когда они внутри структуры собираемого проекта (которой в конечном виде war). Не могу сообразить, каким образом к файлам такого типа указывать путь или обеспечить их нормальную видимость.

Comment: Посмотрите ServletContext.getResource, не помню точно название метода

Comment: Да все люди так делают

Comment: Так надо понимать, что делаешь, если положить файл просто в WEB-INF, то класслоадером вы его вряд ли прочитаете. Ну и пора уже пользоваться готовыми вещами, контейнерами, spring изучить.

Answer (score 1):

`AnyClass.getClassLoader().getResource()`, если я правильно понял задачу.

Конкретно с данными подключения работал так: на этапе сборки они прокидывались как системные переменные, с помощью фильтрации заполнялся .property-файл, который впоследствии считывался с помощью [qatools property loader](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/properties)